# Join 2 select statement in one sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 table here:

**tblPurItem**

-itemID

-retailRecipeID

**tblPosRecipe**

-recipeID

-recipeTypeID

***retailRecipeID = recipeID***

In here, I have 2 different select statement. Now, how to join in one query? Below, the way I'm trying but not working yet.

**SQL**

```
SELECT A.itemID, A.categoryID, A.purchaseMeasurementID, A.stockMeasurementID, 
A.calculationMeasurementID, A.itemName, A.itemDescription, A.itemPrice, A.lastPrice, A.averagePrice, 
A.itemType, A.purchaseStatus, A.cutStock, A.chargeOut, A.retailItem, A.consignment, 
A.marginConsignment, A.active, 
A.retailRecipeID
, (SELECT B.itemCategoryName FROM tblPurItemCategory B WHERE A.categoryID = B.itemcategoryID LIMIT 1) AS 
itemCategoryName
, (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE A.purchaseMeasurementID= C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS purchasemeasurementName
, (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE A.stockMeasurementID= C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS stockmeasurementName
, (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE A.calculationMeasurementID= C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS calculationmeasurementName
 FROM tblPurItem A 

JOIN(SELECT D.recipeID, D.recipeTypeID, D.measurementID, D.defaultBarcode, 
D.retailDefaultSellingPrice, E.posRecipeType, F.measurementName
FROM tblPosRecipe D 
LEFT JOIN tblPosRecipeType E
ON D.recipeTypeID = E.posRecipeTypeID
LEFT JOIN tblPurMeasurement F
ON D.measurementID = F.measurementID
LEFT JOIN tblPosRecipe 
ON A.retailRecipeID = D.recipeID)
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your query.

```
SELECT A.itemID, A.categoryID, A.purchaseMeasurementID, A.stockMeasurementID, 
    A.calculationMeasurementID, A.itemName, A.itemDescription, A.itemPrice, A.lastPrice, A.averagePrice, 
    A.itemType, A.purchaseStatus, A.cutStock, A.chargeOut, A.retailItem, A.consignment, 
    A.marginConsignment, A.active, 
    A.retailRecipeID
    , (SELECT B.itemCategoryName FROM tblPurItemCategory B WHERE A.categoryID = B.itemcategoryID LIMIT 1) AS 
    itemCategoryName
    , (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE A.purchaseMeasurementID= C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS purchasemeasurementName
    , (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE A.stockMeasurementID= C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS stockmeasurementName
    , (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE A.calculationMeasurementID= C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS  calculationmeasurementName
    , D.recipeID, D.recipeTypeID, D.measurementID, D.defaultBarcode, D.retailDefaultSellingPrice, E.posRecipeType, F.measurementName
FROM tblPurItem A 
INNER JOIN tblPosRecipe D ON A.retailRecipeID = D.recipeID
LEFT JOIN tblPosRecipeType E ON D.recipeTypeID = E.posRecipeTypeID
LEFT JOIN tblPurMeasurement F ON D.measurementID = F.measurementID
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
SELECT A.itemID, A.categoryID, A.purchaseMeasurementID, A.stockMeasurementID, 
A.calculationMeasurementID, A.itemName, A.itemDescription, A.itemPrice, A.lastPrice, A.averagePrice, 
A.itemType, A.purchaseStatus, A.cutStock, A.chargeOut, A.retailItem, A.consignment, 
A.marginConsignment, A.active, A.retailRecipeID, 
    (SELECT B.itemCategoryName FROM tblPurItemCategory B WHERE A.categoryID = B.itemcategoryID LIMIT 1) AS itemCategoryName, 
    (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE A.purchaseMeasurementID = C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS purchasemeasurementName, 
     (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE A.stockMeasurementID = 
C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS stockmeasurementName, 
        (SELECT C.measurementName FROM tblPurMeasurement C WHERE A.calculationMeasurementID = 
C.measurementID LIMIT 1) AS calculationmeasurementName,
        D.recipeID, D.recipeTypeID, D.measurementID, D.defaultBarcode, 
        D.retailDefaultSellingPrice, E.posRecipeType, F.measurementName
FROM tblPurItem A 

LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT recipeID,recipeTypeID,measurementID,defaultBarcode,retailDefaultSellingPrice
      FROM tblPosRecipe D 
LEFT JOIN tblPosRecipeType E ON D.recipeTypeID = E.posRecipeTypeID
LEFT JOIN tblPurMeasurement F ON D.measurementID = F.measurementID
LEFT JOIN tblPosRecipe  ON A.retailRecipeID = D.recipeID)
```